# Creating Data Source for Entity Data Model

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, datasource, objectdatasource

I am trying use MySql and Entity Framework, using Connector/Net 6.1 with this as a reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

However my project is WebApplication instead of WinForms. I have sucessfully created entities, but I am not able to cerate Data Source for WebApplication (or MVC), since create command under menus and Data Sources window is missing (window says: There are no data sources to show for the selected project). However I can do it for WinForms/Console application.

I can't figure out why web projects don't allow me to create the Data Sources. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are using [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx) control.
Devart Team 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect 
ADO.NET data providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite with
Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL support